# Where to connect Y capacitor with a low side switching element?

Tags: capacitor, switch-mode-power-supply, adapter

I was working on a power adapter, and we had a synchronous rectifier in the positive high side rail.

We have a Y capacitor between primary ground and secondary ground - between "A" and "B" in the diagram.

[image]

We are now looking to change the high side rectifier to a low side one - which side of the switching element does the Y capacitor go to - transformer side (B) or output side (C)?

[image]

Also, what are the benefits / advantages / disadvantages between having the switching element on the top or bottom side??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will now go between point A (as previous) to point C.

> *Also, what are the benefits / advantages / disadvantages between
> having the switching element on the top or bottom side??*

In your second circuit, the Y capacitor can also go on the top side here: -

[image]

It can also go here: -

[image]